# How can I choose databases once in SQL Server 2005/2008 maintenance plan tasks?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to choose the databases I want to operate on **once** in my maintenance plan without having to choose them for each separate task?  I have a setup that precludes me from choosing the "All user databases" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the sql server team has not implemented custom groups for maintenance plans.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=304835

I left a comment at the bottom a while back - perhaps I should create a suggestions to be able to tag databases to create groups.